# How to bring fieldLabel without colon for combo box in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

can anybody tell How to bring  fieldLabel without colon for combo box  in extjs

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use labelSeparator : "" config of combobox to fix the issue.

Refer below example

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
    store: states,
    queryMode: 'local',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'abbr',
    labelSeparator : "",
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Thanks, sure it will work.